# Flutter Hero widget not working as expected

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation, flutter-widget

I'm trying to use Hero animation for pass widget from a screen to another. I was following the simple example on flutter.dev page, but it seems not work.

I have two screen, ScreenOne and ScreenTwo, both StatefulWidget. ScreenOne contains a list of widget and on tap i should navigate to ScreenTwo and use Hero animation.

This is ScreenOne portion of code for navigate to ScreenTwo and the hero widget

```
 Material(
        child: SizedBox(
          width: double.infinity,
          child: InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) {
                return ScreenTwo(
                  imageUrl : "anUrl",
                );
              }));

            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                children: [
                  Hero(
                    tag: "imageHero",
                    child: Image(
                      width: 60,
                      height: 60,
                      image:
                          Image.network("anUrl").image,
                    ),
                  ),
                  // Other widgets
```

And this is on ScreenTwo

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(),
  body: Container(
    child: Hero(
      tag: "imageHero",
      child: Image(
        width: 60,
        height: 60,
        image: Image.network("anUrl").image,
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

}

Now, when i navigate to ScreenTwo, i don't see the Hero animation. What's wrong?

Comment: Can you try to navigate with `Navigator.of(context).push(...)` instead of  `Navigator.push(...)` ? https://github.com/flutter/website/blob/master/examples/_animation/basic_hero_animation/main.dart

Comment: It doesn't work.

Comment: And did you try to use StatelessWidget instead of StatfulWidget ?

Answer (score -1):

make the tag field a variable and use it for both , for example

```
int imageId = 1;

 Hero(
                tag: imageId,
                child: Image(
                  width: 60,
                  height: 60,
                  image:
                      Image.network("anUrl").image,
                ),
```

and use it for both routes